# How can I have two divs inside a container such that when resizing one the other automatically resizes to fill the container?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm not sure how best to explain this, but basically what I want is a container div which is 100% of my screen with two divs inside that which are 50% of the height.  I want it so that the user can resize the top div between 20%-80% of the container div's height and have the lower div automatically fill the container without overflowing it.  I'm running into two problems:

1. If I set the height of the top div to 50% (either with CSS or a DOMContentLoaded function that sets height equal to one half of the container's offsetHeight) it will not allow the user to shrink it below that size.
2. Apparently onresize does not work in divs in Chrome, so I can't find a way to modify the lower div's height.

The questions I have are:

1. Is this even possible to do?
2. Would it be better to just put some element between the two divs and use the html5 draggable on it?  The only browser I need to support is Google Chrome.
3. Or am I better off using frames?

External javascript libraries are not allowed.  So no jQuery.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function set_top_div_height() {
            var container_height = document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight;
            var top_div = document.getElementById('top');
            top_div.style.height = container_height / 2 + "px";
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }

        #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: solid black 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #top {
            width 100%;
            min-height: 20%;
            max-height: 80%;
            resize: vertical;
            overflow: auto;
            border-bottom: solid black 1px;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        #bottom {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        Top
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        Bottom
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a much better solution using html5 and draggable:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update_size(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var top_div = document.getElementById('top');
        var bottom_div = document.getElementById('bottom');
        var left_height = document.getElementById('left').offsetHeight;
        var new_top_height = Math.floor(ev.clientY);
        var new_bottom_height = left_height - new_top_height - 4;
        top_div.style.height =  new_top_height + "px";
        bottom_div.style.height = new_bottom_height + "px";
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        update_size(ev);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var top_div = document.getElementById('top');
        var bottom_div = document.getElementById('bottom');
        var left_height = document.getElementById('left').offsetHeight;
        var new_top_height = Math.floor((left_height - 4) / 2);
        var new_bottom_height = left_height - new_top_height - 4;
        top_div.style.height =  new_top_height + "px";
        bottom_div.style.height = new_bottom_height + "px";
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    div {
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #left {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }

    #right {
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        clear: right;
        border-left: solid black 1px;
    }

    #top {
        width 100%;
        height: 50%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    #seperator {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: black;
    }

    #bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="top" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="update_size(event);">
            Top
        </div>
        <div id="seperator" draggable="true">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="bottom" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="update_size(event);">
            Bottom
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer to part of my question by creating a function to resize the bottom div and using setTimeout to just poll for updates.  So now the only question left is, how can I change the height of my top div to 50% without causing Chrome to then block it from going smaller than that size again later?

Answer (score 0):

dont set the height of top div.

remove

```
top_div.style.height = container_height / 2 + "px";
```

set the height of bottom div to 100%

```
#bottom {
height:100%;
}
```

top div will be min-height (20%) when page loads. And it depends on content height also.

Comment: How do I force both to be 50% when the page loads instead of 20% though?  I want both to start at 50% regardless of their content and allow the user to shrink the top down to 20% or expand it up to 80% manually.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is set `min-height` and `max-height` to both divs and on resize set the % `height` in such a way that the sum of both heights always be 100%.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top_block"></div>
  <div class="bottom_block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.container{ height: 100%; border: 1px solid salmon; }
div.container > div{ min-height: 20%; max-height: 80%; }
div.container > div.top_block{ height: 50%; background-color: lightgreen; }
div.container > div.bottom_block{ height: 50%; background-color: dodgerblue; }
```

As you can see, both divs will have height between min 20% and max 80% and you control this with the `height`.

If you set it to 100%, both divs will have 80% height, because it is the max value you set to it.

The same to the min, if you set the height to 0%, it will cause the divs to have 20% height.

As you don't want an overflow, you should control the % heights with javascript in such a way that when the top div have 70% height the bottom have 30% set.

I hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is with using the CSS 'resize' attribute in conjunction with setting the 'height' value.  No matter how I set the height, either with CSS or javascript, that value seems to overwrite the min-height so when the use tries to resize the div it won't let it get smaller than whatever I set the height to, even if min-height was set lower.